# How to make a PUT request with Apache Olingo?

Tags: java, apache, odata, http-method, olingo

I am trying to transfer an entity via a HTTP `PUT` request using following code.

```
public ClientEntity createEntity(URI absoluteUri,
        ClientEntity ce) {

    ODataEntityCreateRequest<ClientEntity> request = client
            .getCUDRequestFactory().getEntityCreateRequest(absoluteUri, ce);
    request.setAccept("application/json;odata.metadata=minimal");       
    ODataEntityCreateResponse<ClientEntity> response = request.execute();
    return response.getBody();
}
```

The function `getEntityCreateRequest`, however, only creates a `POST` request and allows (as far as I know) no alteration of the used `HttpMethod`.

Unfortunately, `ODataEntityUpdateRequest` is also not an option, because this request only allows the `HttpMethod` `PATCH` or `REPLACE`.

Within the documentation I have found a function `setMethod(HttpMethod method)`, but this method is only available for the server not the client implementation (https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata4/org/apache/olingo/server/api/ODataRequest.html).

Further I discovered `setUseXHTTPMethod(boolean value)`, which tunnels `PUT, MERGE, PATCH, DELETE` via `POST`. I checked my client's configuration to make sure, that `isUseXHTTPMethod` is `false`, which it is. (Reference to functions:  https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata4/org/apache/olingo/client/api/Configuration.html)

Hence I am wondering how to make a `PUT` request with Apache Olingo?

Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ODataEntityUpdateRequest**  with **UpdateType.REPLACE** should be equivalent to a PUT method.

Notice [the source code](https://github.com/apache/olingo-odata4/blob/master/lib/client-api/src/main/java/org/apache/olingo/client/api/communication/request/cud/UpdateType.java), line 31.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much. This solves the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Implement the [updateEntity](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/write/tutorial_write.html#32-implement-the-updateentity-method) method.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. You are completely right, the `updateEntity` has the required method. :) Thank you!